# update checkbox value in laravel 8 (blade/ controller )

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-8, updatecheck

I'm beginner in laravel and I want to update multiple checkboxes in database ..
when I click at update button automatically my inputs show old value also my permissions are checked by old value to update it ..

relation between user and permission is manytomany .. I have another table named userpermissions who has id_user and id_permission

this is my update form in ( edit.blade.php)

```
<form action="{{ url('users/'.$user->id) }}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('PUT')
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="form-control" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                @error('name')
                                                    <ul class="alert"><li class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</li></ul>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required class="form-control" value="{{ $user->email }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div  class="form-group">
                                            @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                                                <?php if( in_array($permission->id, $user->userPermissions->pluck('permission_id')->toArray())){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
                                               {{ $permission->name }}
                                                @if($loop->iteration % 3 == 0 ) <br> @else @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-right mt-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

and this is my controller where I think have a problem with methods  :

edit function

```
 public function edit(User $user)
{
    $permissions = Permission::get();
    return view('users.edit', compact('user','permissions'));
}
```

update function :

```
public function update(UserRequest $request,User $user)
{
    $user->update(
        $request->only('name', 'email')
    );
    $user->userPermissions()->save($request->input('data'));
    return redirect()->back()->with('status','user updated !');
}
```

and this is my functio store :

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
    $user = User::create(
        $request->only('name', 'email', 'password')
    );
    $user->userPermissions()->createMany($request->input('data'));
    return redirect()->back()->with('status','Utilisateur ajouté !');
}
```

Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user->userPermissions()->save($request->input('data'));
```

One important thing to understand here, is that **save()** on relation doesn't remove old values from pivot table, it just add more values to it(no distinction check). You need something like refresh functionality. Look at [attaching\detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) or [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations), second one is more convenient.

In first case before saving permissions you can do this

```
// remove all old permissions
$user->userPermissions()->detach();
// update them with new one
$user->userPermissions()->attach($request->input('data'));
```

In second case, which is less verbose then first one you just need to pass and array of permissions to user object.

```
// this will do both things which we did before
$user->userPermissions()->sync($request->input('data'))
```

But i encourage you to read the docs and ask questions after ;)

Another thing which i saw and its not related to the current topic is

```
$user->userPermissions->pluck('permission_id')->toArray()
```

you are using lazy load inside of foreach loop which means that on each iteration of the loop you are making a query to the database(N + 1 problem). You can [preload/eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default) userPermissions instead of loading them on a fly by declaring with relation in your User model like this

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['userPermissions'];
    ...
}
```

and then in your **User** object will have **userPermissions** property which you can compare to permissions.

Hope that you get main idea and info was useful for you!

Comment: Thanks Sergey, it works well!
Yeah alright I will read the docs ..